# How to add custom REST controller with @RestController annotation?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have this dilemma.

As from 2.14 version of GeoServer, there is a new way to write rest controller
using @RestController annotation and extending RestBaseController.class

But after starting the server I can't see the custom rest path.

How do I create custom REST services with the new way?

Comment: why do you want to add new RESTControllers?

Comment: To add functionality to ease tasks in our project.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question is this in the controller I have to Annotate it like this 
while extending RestBaseController.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(RestBaseController.ROOT_PATH + "/test")
public class HelloController extends RestBaseController {

}
```

And in the applicationContext.xml I have to write this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="<pakagesToScan>.*"/>

</beans>
```

And last but not least you have to Add your new module to the dependencies of GeoServer